# How to get a refresh_token with an auto-approved response?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I have the following code:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['logout']))
{
  unset($_SESSION['upload_token ']);
}

if (isset($_GET['code']))
{
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['upload_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset($_SESSION['upload_token']) && $_SESSION['upload_token'])
{
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['upload_token']);
  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired())
  {
    echo "The access token is expired.<br>"; // Debug
    $client->refreshToken(json_decode($_SESSION['upload_token']));
    unset($_SESSION['upload_token']);
  }
}
else
{
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
}
```

and am receiving the following error:

```
Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'The OAuth 2.0 access token has expired, and a refresh token is not available. Refresh tokens are not returned for responses that were auto-approved.'
```

I am assuming I am getting this error because the response was auto-approved.

What should be changed?

UPDATE: I've tried adding this to my code:

```
$client->setAccessType("online");
$client->setApprovalPrompt("auto");
```

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101551/google-oauth-api-store-and-retrieve-tokens-after-first-login-and-authorization).  I still am receiving the same error of missing refresh token.

UPDATE:  After kroikie's update, my code looks like the following:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");
$client->setAccessType("offline");
$client->setApprovalPrompt("auto");
$client->setApplicationName("Appraisal App");
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

if (isset($_REQUEST['logout']))
{
  unset($_SESSION['upload_token ']);
}

if (isset($_GET['code']))
{
  $resp = $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['upload_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $array = get_object_vars(json_decode($resp));
  // store and use $refreshToken to get new access tokens
  $refreshToken = $array['refreshToken'];
  $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset($_SESSION['upload_token']) && $_SESSION['upload_token'])
{
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['upload_token']);
  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired())
  {
    echo "The access token is expired.  Let Raph know that you saw this.<br>";
    $client->refreshToken($refreshToken);
    unset($_SESSION['upload_token']);
  }
}
else
{
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
}
```

Unfortunately, I still receive the same fatal error when the refresh token is needed.

Answer (score 6):

When the access type is offline, an access token and a refresh token are returned when the user first grants data access. The access token can be used to access the user's data, and the refresh token is stored and used to get a new access token when the initial access token has expired.

So try using offline access type

```
$client->setAccessType('offline');
```

and use the refresh token to refresh the client's access token

```
// $refreshToken is retrieved from the response of the
// user's initial granting access
$client->refreshToken($refreshToken)
```

UPDATE:
To get the refresh token use something like:

```
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $resp = $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $array = get_object_vars(json_decode($resp));
  // store and use $refreshToken to get new access tokens
  $refreshToken = $array['refreshToken'];
}
```

Comment: Does $refreshToken need to be stored earlier or is it already defined? If it's not defined, how would I define it?

Comment: Updated answer with a bit more detail.

Comment: Thank you for the update, unfortunately I am still receving the same error.  I've posted my entire code. What am I missing?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: i have this problem too. could you please post an answer of how did you finally solved it? thank you.

Comment: I too have this issue. I tried incorporating the above code, but for me that section never executes, because the 'code' param is NOT set.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to use the offline access type, you have two choices: either you force the approval prompt (so you never get an auto-approved response):

```
$client->setAccessType("offline");
$client->setApprovalPrompt("force");
```

Or you ignore the refresh token and simply get a new auto-approved authorization when your current token is expired. I never tested this but since no user action is required for approval, I assume it works.

You can read more about this here (Change #3: Server-side auto-approval): http://googlecode.blogspot.ca/2011/10/upcoming-changes-to-oauth-20-endpoint.html

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's seems that the error is in the code, but in my case was not.

I had the same problem and tried all kind of solution, but the error was in the console.developers.google.com configuration.

I thought was not necessary to confirm the domain in the Credentials configuration.

So when i did it, so the code stopped giving the error.